# How to infer correct return type of a function given a type map?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that, given it knows about the mapping between a key and a type, should return the correct type when called with the matching key.

Below is a simplified example of my use case. I'm almost there but I'm missing something.

**Note**: this is for a library and we don't know the types as users will provide them.

```
type Plane = {
    name: string;
    wings: number;
};

type Car = {
    name: string;
    wheels: number;
};

type Vehicles = {
    cars: Car;
    planes: Plane;
};

type TypeMap = { [key: string]: any };

type Mapper<VehicleMapType extends TypeMap = TypeMap> = {
    getVehicle<
        VehicleType extends
            | Extract<keyof VehicleMapType, string>
            | never = Extract<keyof VehicleMapType, string>
    >(
        type: VehicleType
    ): VehicleMapType[VehicleType];
};

const mapper: Mapper<Vehicles> = null;

const vehicle1 = mapper.getVehicle('cars');
// I have a Car!
console.log(vehicle1);

const getVehicles = <
    VehicleMapType extends TypeMap = TypeMap,
    VehicleType extends Extract<keyof VehicleMapType, string> | never = Extract<
        keyof VehicleMapType,
        string
    >
>(
    type: VehicleType
): VehicleMapType[VehicleType] => {
    return null;
};

const vehicle2 = getVehicles<Vehicles>('cars');
// How can I get a Car instead of a Car | Plane?
console.log(vehicle2);
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

Besides, we also face an issue in the Mapper implementation as you can see in this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwHbQLxQN4FgBQV9RIIC2EAXFAM7ABOAlkgOYDcuBUA7g45RUgK7EARhBqscAX3G5QkKAGEENKOmx4CRUhWr0m49hwAWECHF6FBIsbim4Z4aADUIhugGM4ESisxsCbpXNFa3V8MEQUc3hkCHFbHHs5ABUHAFkEMB8MKABtAGsIEG1abgBdCmQQKHjcAHpaqAA5AHtgaGBDBGAoDrpvPqgAM2blBCg4OiEaJSrkABNOaDnmpABybrykZo4oSt6mXaFm-m6O9odKOoak4yquODgoESgwGmaANzo5iAWhKv5KKJLjhZNB0mBIDQADzOVweCDglJyCAADzaSDm3iRCIyPmx4IAfFk-PhGBBgLD3J4oST2FBKfDsVBUejMbS6QQAD5QACiaOmbmAUIKIGag3pLipOLA2IANFQSkwCeyOVBuSh3qIfHzaAhBcLCmKJXDPIiHPKdNxlaEoASABQq-CgigMzzY2kAShdkvhZsgOVdEGxpTi0hwbhW1CgxAykIo4MhMJ9nkoRNUfnqUAA6oYqgB+PxkinJiB20Ee3w2yhcYBuQxQMsOCtqDkBQFQVYBGiUVYUFuqmjk-g0JCV1UaEjkDtjLurWWOghGExmCgAFgXEhVm4SNvwbegq3CMR7fYXg+Aw9H-fHminqzGR5Qc4X+C4THMACYN1u7LuoN9BgQfg4GAMgFw6N4dhQHYeRoN4aDtVZ+CQTZtlHTUTXOSBVg9fQCG3fBtxqcNI26DCpQARh8GMIVEAA6ItA0Qrse1wq4oAASSgTpNV2BQlAAQlwCMkEoZpPDouBmkYO1yPhCi2J3UEoAAcXJQNKBpG1Az9aAWQgDEsTSXF0HxDJ520ksmX0wzeX5PUhRFI0dIyOUFV0RgiXVCBNWUdAdQFIUFyc8UXJlc0F0tJhaWtNMG1pZ1jSld0cArVAiTC7EAyshwQ1-ESo0YktzDU4tMM0jS4sbSA0qJftqzoWt62qiBm1pfcOxY3sxzpc9Lx6jlbwoe8oFnCzxyXUxzHXP8CPw392A6w8Ii8brrwIPqRwGukhunF4VufP9X24T8fxtbdaQAoCQLAo6ekMSDCAgGC4JGRDkNQjh0JLHoHBwvCiPy0ioDkzwPx8IryuYwJ-vYgAJbZRuQTioCLPjgigBhqAgBAFiNMYMe5aIUALEjRPEiBJOk2SSw-XCgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to

- supply both generics when invoking the function (in your example, you are only supplying `Vechicles`), or
- use a functional abstraction to infer the types, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZygXigCUIBjAe3gBMAebBFVAGigENkQA+AbgFgAofqEhQAciwC2ESvigBvKMgkQAXFDpI0UAL68+Q6AAUANm2gExk6QDI5UAO4Nsq5AFdxAIwjxtu-VADCLN7mSta2dgAWEBBGTgpunt46-ILg0ABqEBGIJEYQuASy-FBQJEFxgfC6JWAmyPmqxqa6yQJ6aVAAsixgkPDUACpQEAAewBDIlLhwGhhY2BwyRXwlqBDAmdm5ENTow2MTU1AA1lhkAGZQAxwAFPqq6ACUqgMA2ugAui26-OTIdFBxD0+qpur0vNRNjk8gslsUoGsNllodA7mlHnJ4SU-gCAG6kLYw1RQ7YFTErEqUsrwOKyRSSVQAchYpSCjOYkWisVUABYtIwsZTaqZafSVFBmVBhfV2fZHKoAEz8wWtSmlMj-YBQeD5FxGLUEfEkQn5V76L6CxCXG467B64AYnXAFzwZDa3X66qU4AReBkOwKCABgCi8D98BujJcyGOyH9bvxJqg+kZjy9Wn4rV+GrxyO2AEYZEDwfAAHSIkl5SPU7CprhQAD0DYCQRSbSbUAA4hMvDkoOdoyRgIgNSwjKx3OoWEOR8hlG2cVqwDljgAxP3iGSDfbjSbTehoTA4W5kF7PKC7HeHXCnEAXK63W8PDF4RZvT74RbLEpOl1u2+flAZCvLeFp8FmfCUKQJg6uqmpQImKJxJW+S6IuCLrChZLLiQa4bjciGkmm2bwYReQKjIFZ5jC1blHWjbNpU-BAA)

```ts
type StringKeys = Record<string, any>;

type Named = { name: string };
type Plane = Named & { wings: number };
type Car = Named & { wheels: number };

type Vehicles = {
  cars: Car;
  planes: Plane;
};

type Mapper<T extends StringKeys> = {
  getVehicle<K extends keyof T>(type: K): T[K];
};

const mapper: Mapper<Vehicles> = {
  getVehicle (type) {
    const vechicles: Vehicles = {
      cars: {name: 'a car', wheels: 4},
      planes: {name: 'a plane', wings: 2},
    };
    const result = vechicles[type];
    if (result) return result;
    throw new Error('unknown vehicle type');
  }
};

const vehicle1 = mapper.getVehicle('cars'); // Car


// Generic functional abstraction:

const pickFrom = <T extends StringKeys>(o: T): <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => T[K] => {
  return key => o[key];
};

declare const vehicles: Vehicles;
const getVehicles = pickFrom(vehicles);
const vehicle2 = getVehicles('cars'); // Car
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the first solution I had but I really need to avoid the mapper. End goal is to have react hooks thafunct uses the mapper under the hood, and I'd really like to avoid having a `getHooks` function just for types

Comment: @GildasGarcia (For now, at least) generics are an all-or-nothing affair in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks again :) One more thing though. We also face an issue in the implementations. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: @GildasGarcia Your [most recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71155027/4) includes a link to a TS playground with the same code as before (except for some commented lines). Is there something about the refactored example that I've provided that doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Yes, the implementation has issues too. I left a Why comment. Thanks!

Comment: In short, I'd like to provide type safety to the implementation of the mapper. It should only allows Car to be returned when type is "cars", etc

Comment: @GildasGarcia Oh, I see: you were having trouble **implementing** a mapper. See my updated answer.

Comment: I believe I didn't layout our constraints and requirements correctly. I'll accept your answer and will create a new question. Thanks a lot!